# Exception caught in debug mode but not in release

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have a Google Sign In Flow in my new Flutter App. (First Flutter App). If cancel is pressed, the app crashes. From what I have found, the easiest solution is to wrap the sign in flow in a try-catch statement.

This works fine in debug mode. The error is caught and the circle and the view is reset to how it was from start. When a sign in process starts I have a circle

But when I run in release mode it just crashes. I have tried some different versions but none have worked.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (user != null) {
      return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
          body: loadDataAndGoToMain(),
        ),
      );
    }
    double deviceWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
        body: SizedBox(
          width: deviceWidth,
          child: _isLoading
              ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
              : Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    backgroundImage(),
                    if (Platform.isIOS) ...{
                      FractionallySizedBox(
                          widthFactor: 0.85, child: appleButton(context)),
                    },
                    FractionallySizedBox(
                        widthFactor: 0.85, child: googleButton(context)), <-- Problem
                    FractionallySizedBox(
                      widthFactor: 0.85,
                      child: TextButton(
                        style: getStyle(Colors.white),
                        onPressed: () {
                          toggleState();
                          Navigator.of(context).push<void>(
                            MaterialPageRoute<void>(
                              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                return const MainView();
                              },
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        child: const Text("Continue Offline"),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Google button:

```
Widget googleButton(BuildContext context) {
    return SignInButton(
      Buttons.Google,
      text: "Sign in with Google",
      onPressed: () async {
        toggleState();
        startGoogleSignIn();
      },
    );
  }
```

startGoogleSignIn:

```
Future<void> startGoogleSignIn() async {
    try {
      final user = await signInWithGoogle();
      await loadUserData(user!);
      Navigator.of(context).push<void>(
        MaterialPageRoute<void>(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return const MainView();
          },
        ),
      );
    } on PlatformException { <- I tried this just because it did not work with one catch. 
      toggleState();
    } catch (error) {
      toggleState();
    }
  }
```

signInWithGoogle:

```
Future<User?> signInWithGoogle() async {
  // Trigger the authentication flow
  final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser;
  googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

  // Obtain the auth details from the request
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth =
      await googleUser?.authentication;

  // Create a new credential
  final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken,
    idToken: googleAuth?.idToken,
  );

  // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
  final authResult =
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
  return authResult.user;
}
```